# How to use Unit of Work pattern for Save to provide transaction feature with out msdtc?

Tags: sql, design-patterns, c#-4.0, unit-of-work

I am writing a method that has to save the changes made to entities in the database. How can I use Unit Of Work Pattern for my Save method?

Answer (score 1):

Reference to a classical Martin Fowler's [Unit of Work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) design

So basically Save() would be like this

```cs
public void Save()
{
  try
  {
     // save changes into database then commit
     // ...
     unitOfWork.Commit();
  }
  catch
  {
    unitOfWork.Rollback();
   }
}
```

Also see an interface example on stackexchange Code Review site: [Unit Of Work Interface](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/276/interface-for-unit-of-work-pattern-and-repository-pattern)